# How to format rename json key in a forEach loop that is also checking for the value of the json key pairs

Tags: javascript, json

I initially had the following json **weightLoss and Strength are checkbox values either on or false**

```
{ 
  name: 'Anders',
  package: 'Silver',
  email: 'email@email.com',
  subject: 'fdsafa',
  weightLoss: 'on', // or false
  strength: false,
  message: 'fdsasfdsdafsdafasdfasd'
}
```

Which I then run the following for each loop to change the 'on' values (or `!= false`) to the name of the key

```
Object.entries(payLoadReason).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value != false) {
        payLoadReason[key] = key;
        }
    });
```

I then get this formatted json, ***if strenth were set to 'on' it's value would also change to it's key `strength`***

```
{ 
  name: 'name',
  package: 'package',
  email: 'email',
  subject: 'subject',
  weightLoss: 'weightLoss', // or false
  strength: false,
  message: 'message'
}
```

What I want to do next is to rename the key's of any value that was originally **'on'** and change the key to `reason` so I end up with formatted Json like below so I can iterate through it in a send grid handlebars template

```
{
"data":{
      "reasonArray":[
         {
            "reason":"weightLoss"
         },
         {
            "reason":"strength"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

handle bars template

```
 <ol>
   {{#each data.reasonArray}}
    <li>{{this.reason}} </li>
  {{/each}}
 </ol>
```

The orignal Json is coming from the formState, so it is the whole forms state at submit.

**Update**

Attempt from Diago's answer. Results in just an array with the values. I need a key of reason with a value of the original key inside a `reasonArray[]` and a `data {}` Here is what I got from the answer

```
[
  'Anders',
  'Silver',
  'email@email.com', 
  'fdsafa',
  'on',
  false,
  'fdsasfdsdafsdafasdfasd'
]
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how you're getting step 3 from step 2. "weightloss" isn't a `falsy` value, and "Sport" isn't in your step 2 data at all. Could you clarify the transformation you're looking for?

Comment: thus false values come if I check a box or not in a form. So if weightLost is not equal to false then it will change to have the same name as the key. But I want to somehow also change the key of weightLoss to reason, because I am going to have multiple checkboxes. I need to reword somethings hold on. I'll update my question.

Comment: I added more notes as bold items above, hope it clears things up a little

Comment: I'll go through it again. Are you aware that no matter if it's checked or not, a checkbox's value won't change from "on" ? Does that not matter?

Comment: I think you really should find a different looping solution in your handlebars template.

Comment: I am changing the value after the fact. I am fine with it originally being false or on

Comment: How is "Sport" in the result when it isn't in the input?  Is it from a hypothetical other object with `sport: 'on'` ?  Can you supply complete input and desired output?

Comment: sorry sport is supposed to be strength. I am tired

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I feel you can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to achieve your goal:

```
const normalizedData = Object.values(payLoadReason).reduce((acc, cur) => {
   cur.reasons = [];

   if(cur.weightLoss === 'on') {
      cur.reasons.push('weightLoss');
   }

   if(cur.strength === 'on') {
      cur.reasons.push('strength');
   }

   return [...acc, cur];
}, []);

console.log(normalizedData);
```

**EDIT:** Now using `map`:

```
const normalizedData = Object.values(payLoadReason).map(item => {
   item.reasons = [];

   if(item.weightLoss === 'on') {
      item.reasons.push('weightLoss');
   }

   if(item.strength === 'on') {
      item.reasons.push('strength');
   }

   return item;
});

console.log(normalizedData);
```

Comment: Don't use `reduce` to build an array, use `map` and/or `filter`. Also this doesn't seem to work with `cur` not being an object.

Comment: I added an update as I attempted what you answered, but am still stuck, hopefully it makes more sense now.